# ссылка добавляет лишние пиксели

Tags: html, css

есть ссылка с классом logo а также картинка внутри.

Проблема в том, что картинка ровно 40х40, а ссылка почему-то 40х44, кто может сказать, почему? И как можно исправить?

Падинги, маржины сброшены до 0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не добавляйте код картинками.

Comment: @void почему? лого ведь, нужно чтобы кликабельным было

Comment: Вы не поняли: не публикуйте код картинками в вопросе.

Comment: Потому что `img` - это инлайновый элемент, у него есть свой `line-height`, сделайте его `display: block;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

должно помочь добавление следующего свойства картинке:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```